# How to set command line args with the space delimited contents of the first command line argument in zsh

Tags: zsh, command-line-arguments

I will be getting one command line argument in the script I'm writing which will itself be a space delimited list of the actual command line arguments. I'd like to set the arguments of the current script with these arguments. How might I accomplish that?

I'd like to use `set --` but I'm not sure how this would work.

E.g.
Given arguments to my script: -a -b -c

```
echo $1 # prints "-a -b -c"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `set -- "${(z)1}"`. This will split `$1` into words, handling quoting the same way the shell itself does:

```
% cat script.zsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
set -- "${(z)1}"
for arg; do
  echo "==$arg=="
done

% ./script.zsh "-a -b -c -d'has spaces'"
==-a==
==-b==
==-c==
==-d'has spaces'==
```

If you also want to remove a level of quotes, use `"${(@Q)${(z)1}}"` instead.